# AdjustPan analog in IOS and get/lost focus for UITextField

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, adjustpan

I use VS with Xamarin (not Xamarin.Forms). 
Right now it looks like

[image: AdjustPan]

Is there anything like Android AdjustPan in IOs.

And second question - how to get/lost focus of UITextField programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there anything like Android AdjustPan in IOs.

You can use third-party tool to manage your keyboard position.

For example : [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) , you could add it via NuGet [here](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Xamarin.IQKeyboardManager).

> And second question - how to get/lost focus of UITextField programmatically?

*Get focus:*

```
textfield.BecomeFirstResponder();
```

*Lost focus:*

```
textfield.ResignFirstResponder();
```

Comment: Thank you for help